# How can I get paredit mode when doing eval-expression?

Tags: emacs, elisp, paredit

I love Emacs' paredit-mode, but I miss it very sorely when doing `eval-expression` (`M-:`).  How can I have paredit in the minibuffer when doing `eval-expression`?  Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add a function to `minibuffer-setup-hook`, like so:

```
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'conditionally-enable-paredit-mode)
(defun conditionally-enable-paredit-mode ()
  "enable paredit-mode during eval-expression"
  (if (eq this-command 'eval-expression)
      (paredit-mode 1)))
```

Comment: Not bad, but as you allude to that applies paredit to everything (ex. `shell-command`/`M-!`) and not just Emacs Lisp entry in the minibuffer.  I'd prefer that not be the case.

I wonder if I'll end up having to replace `eval-expression` with something that calls a more special read function.

Comment: It enables it only for eval-expression, but maybe you wrote your comment before Trey edited his answer...

Comment: Yup, I did write it before it was a hook looking at `this-command`.  I didn't think of doing that.  Thanks!

Comment: This causes return key to become rebound to `paredit-newline` which is very frustrating. I tried `(local-set-key [return] 'minibuffer-complete-and-exit)` in vain after `(paredit-mode 1)`. What to do?

Comment: @Nordlöw Ahhh... the latest version (I had the beta) does set up a binding for `C-j` - which you might have bound to `return`.  In vanilla Emacs 24.2 the `C-j` and `<return>` are different bindings, so `C-j` is bound to `paredit-newline` and `<return>` is bound to `'exit-minibuffer`.  I'd check your `.emacs` for bindings to those keys, and/or try running Emacs w/out your settings and just load `paredit.el` to see how it behaves.

Answer (score 2):

Add function `paredit-mode` to `eval-expression-minibuffer-setup-hook`, like so

```
(add-hook 'eval-expression-minibuffer-setup-hook #'paredit-mode)
```